# How to add an external View to a HorizontalScrollView in main activity

Tags: android, google-maps

Is it possible to add to a horizontal ScrollView a View which has been created separately in the main Activity?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have reputation to comment but each View Class has addView() function where you can add the view dynamically. So it should be possible as long as you have the view which you want to add.